# How to display data from Textbox to a Gridview using Generic List (Typed List)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generic-list

I have created two TextBoxes to enter the FirstName and LastName of an employee in a web-based ASP.NET application using C# on Visual studio 2010. There is a Button. when I click on it, the values that I enter in the TextBoxes should be displayed in a Gridview without those values being stored in the database. I have already implemented it using ArrayList as shown below. But now I want to implement it using **Generic List (Typed List)**. How can I do that? Can you provide a sample code to execute the above mentioned functionality?

**How can I tweak the code given below, to implement the functionality using Generic List (Typed List)?**

**

```
    protected void btnTextDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList arr;

        if (Session["array"] == null)
        {
            arr = new ArrayList();
        }
        else
        {
            arr = (ArrayList)Session["array"];
        }

        arr.Add(txtName.Text + "," + txtCity.Text); //store textbox values in the array list
        Session["array"] = arr;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("City");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] arrVal;
            arrVal = arr[i].ToString().Split(',');
            dt.Rows.Add(arrVal[0], arrVal[1]);
        }

        gvDisplay.DataSource = dt;
        gvDisplay.DataBind();
    }
```

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`

```
protected void btnTextDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       List<string> list;

        if (Session["list"] == null)
        {
            list = new List<string>();
        }
        else
        {
            list = (List<string>)Session["list"];
        }

        list.Add(txtName.Text + "," + txtCity.Text); //store textbox values in the array list
        Session["list"] = list;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("City");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] arrVal;
            arrVal = list[i].ToString().Split(',');
            dt.Rows.Add(arrVal[0], arrVal[1]);
        }

        gvDisplay.DataSource = dt;
        gvDisplay.DataBind();
    }
```

**A much better approach could be:**

If you define a class as:

```
class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
    protected void btnTextDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Employee> list;
        if (Session["list"] == null)
        {
            list = new List<Employee>();
        }
        else
        {
            list = (List<Employee>)Session["list"];
        }
        list.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = txtName.Text, City = txtCity.Text }); //store textbox values in the array list
        Session["list"] = list;
        gvDisplay.DataSource = list; //directly bind the list to the grid
        gvDisplay.DataBind();
    }
```